# Why are all reflected rays concurrent?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Let us take a point object (real ) for simplicity . Irrespective of where object is located an image is always formed (virtual or real ,at finite distance or at infinite distance ) . So i wanted to know how can we prove that the reflected rays are concurrent and intersect at one single point ?

Comment: look for "diffuse scattering"

Answer (score 0):

It is not so much that all reflected rays are concurrent. Rather all points of the object reflect light in all possible directions. So, no matter at which position the human eye or camera or any receiver is located, it will receive rays of light from all points of the object ( that are in line of sight from that location ).

So, at that location, from each point of the object, there will be a reflected ray, that will pass through that location